# 4G network compatibility in France

Tags: mobile-network, 4g, motorola-moto-g5

I read somewhere ([here](https://geekmps.fr/geeks/1090-comprendre-les-bandes-frequence-4g-des-operateurs-et-des-smartphone)) that in France, in order for the 4G to work ideally with all carriers, one should have a smartphone with the 4G network spec: "FDD-LTE : Bands : 1/3/7/20/28".

I am considering buying the Moto G5 model XT1685 for my brother who lives in France. According to [this site](http://www.phonemore.com/motorola-moto-g5-plus-xt1685-32gb/specs/3210), the 4G network specs of this phone read:

```
LTE Cat6 700/800/850/900/1800/2100/2600 (Bands 1,3,5,7,8,19,20,28)
TD-LTE 2300/2500/2600 (Bands 38,40,41)
```

I can't figure out whether it is a problem or not that I am not seeing "FDD" in these specs. In short: will this phone work perfectly fine in France? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only duplex modes of LTE are TDD and FDD (see [band list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_frequency_bands)) - in other words, non-TD-LTE bands are FDD-LTE.

Generally Europe uses band 20 extensively, but you are still advised to consult your particular carrier.